# BWF import to PT LE doesn't recognize timestamp 

Tags: bwf, workflow, pro-tools, post-production

Hey people!

Yesterday I finished the score for a short film I'm working on. I exported all the cues, each track as stereo BWF, so the sound designer doesn't need to relocate them manually.

The problem is that I got a call from her, saying her Pro Tools doesn't seem to recognize the timestamp of each file.

I don't work on PT (I use Digital Performer) and I cannot check it by myself, but I'm sure PT should allow/understand this type of metadata in BWF files.

Any thoughts about this? I need to solve this ASAP! HELP!!

Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you delivered, but I've seen FTP programs strip out metadata from BWFs. So composers who deliver to us will typically add the timestamp in the file name to avoid this kind of delay. The fastest way to solve this particular issue may be to provide her with an excel spreadsheet of "file name" / Start TC. Doesn't solve the metadata issue, but it should get you through today.

Comment: Just delivered it in a flash memory. I think I'll go the spreadsheet way, but I need to know why this happened so I can avoid this type of problems. Thanks for your input, Steve!

Comment: Have you tried reading the metadata in another piece of software? Try Sound Devices' Wave Agent (http://bit.ly/sozKz). Should be able to read the metadata and tell you quickly if the problem is in your file or on their end...

Comment: Wave Agent displays the correct TC for each file, so I assume the problem is on their end...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing she doesn't have the DV Toolkit or Complete Production Toolkit.  Without one of these, Pro Tools LE won't read SMPTE Timecode.

Do you know whether or not she has one of these?

Comment: Good point. I'll talk with her today and ask it!